# Sql Select If Statement not working but working as simple function without if statement

Tags: sql, select, if-statement, joomla

Need help, am trying to use Select if statement in Sql

```
 $sql = "Select *, 
 (select prod_name from #__mobile_products where prod_id=z.z_prod_id)
 as cell_name  from #__mobile_types AS z
 When z.z_status='1' and z.z_id = '".$vid."'
 else JError::raiseError(404, "Message");
        ";
```

Target Objective is: show list when `z_status=1` and display `J Error` when `z_status=0`. However it's not working. This function works well

```
 $sql = "Select *, 
 (select prod_name from #__mobile_products where prod_id=z.z_prod_id)
 as cell_name  from #__mobile_types AS z
 Where z.z_status='1' and z.z_id = '".$vid."'
        ";
```

However when trying to modify using else statement it does not work.

**Edit - Complete Function Code:-**

```
        $database =& JFactory::getDBO();
    global $Itemid; 

 $sql = "Select *, 
 (select prod_name from #__mobile_products where prod_id=z.z_prod_id)
 as cell_name  from #__mobile_types AS z
 Where z.z_status='1' and z.z_id = '".$vid."'
        ";

    $database->setQuery($sql);
    $rows = $database->loadObjectList();
    return $rows[0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing SQL and PHP and Joomla:  The second query you wrote is the one you want to run.  But the logic needs to be handled in php. Your sql engine doesn't know "else" (which is php) or JError (which is Joomla). Not to speak about the wrong use of " - as you wrote it's just a syntax error.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$sql = "Select *, 
 (select prod_name from #__mobile_products where prod_id=z.z_prod_id)
 as cell_name  from #__mobile_types AS z
 Where z.z_status='1' and z.z_id = " . $db->quote($vid);
$db->setQuery($sql);
if ($result = $db->loadObject()) {
  // the query returned something, you can use the result object
  echo $result->prod_name;
} else {
  if ($db->getErrorNum()) {
    JError::raiseError(500, "Something went horribly wrong, the query returned the error ". $db->getErrorMsg());

  } else {
    echo "Your query returned no records i.e. no records satisfy the z_status=1 condition";
  }
}
```

Finally, 404 is "not found", but it refers to the request, not the data in your application.  You might want to return 500 if the query errors out, and 200 for all other requests. See here for more info on status codes: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Thanks Riccardo Zom - for correcting it, advising best written code standards. The above code though works well when no records found ie z_status is not equal to 1  - but does not display product information  when z_status is equal to 1. I have appended complete function code. Could you advise what is missing

Comment: Thanks, made it work by changing loadobject to loadobjectlist